# Create moving background in live wallpaper using rajawali

Tags: background, live-wallpaper, rajawali

I'm creating a live wallpaper using rajawali. I load an object on it (with this code: [Rajawali object rotation match to camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435305/rajawali-object-rotation-match-to-camera/)) and now I want to set moving image in background for it. Has anyone advice for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created Plane:

```
        mPlane1 = new Plane();
    Material material1 = new Material();
    try {
        material1.addTexture(new Texture("cloud2", R.drawable.cloud2));
    } catch (TextureException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    material1.setColorInfluence(0);
    mPlane1.setMaterial(material1);
    mPlane1.setRotY(180);
    mPlane1.setTransparent(true);
    mPlane1.setPosition(Vector3.X);
    mPlane1.setPosition(-1.6f, 1.2, 1.6);
    getCurrentScene().addChild(mPlane1);
```

and translate it with TranslateAnimation3D:

```
plane1Anim = new TranslateAnimation3D(Vector3.X);
    plane1Anim.setRepeatMode(RepeatMode.INFINITE);
    plane1Anim.setTransformable3D(mPlane1);
    plane1Anim.setDuration(16000);
    getCurrentScene().registerAnimation(plane1Anim);
    plane1Anim.play();
```